# Get Path Of File From Holding Cursor Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, enter

I have Label and event Enter on Label and when event fired I want get whether the cursor is holding a file if cursor holding a file get path of this file

Comment: What you need is drag and drop function for tkinter, see [`tkinterdnd2`](https://pypi.org/project/tkinterdnd2/).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def on_label_click(event):
    # Check if a file is selected
    file_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if file_path:
        label.config(text="Selected File: " + file_path)

# Create the main application window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("File Cursor Check")

# Create the label widget
label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter")
label.pack()

# Bind the event to the label widget
label.bind("<Button-1>", on_label_click)


root.mainloop()
```